# Load testing using Jmeter for POST with very large post data

Tags: rest, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a post request as follows:

```
POST /views/<VIEW_ID>/bulk_update.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.abcd.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

with post data:

```
{
"api_key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"updates":[
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:25:0 -0500","value1":30},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:26:0 -0500","value1":20},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:27:0 -0500","value1":40},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:28:0 -0500","value1":70},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:29:0 -0500","value1":80},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:30:0 -0500","value1":100},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:31:0 -0500","value1":1},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:32:0 -0500","value1":11},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:33:0 -0500","value1":111},
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:34:0 -0500","value1":1111},
.
.
.
.
.(total of >1000 updates)
.
.
.
.
{"timestamp":"2018-01-31 09:35:0 -0500","value1":876},
]
}
```

I have a csv file to store all the timestamps and values.

Is there a simple way to mention all the 1000 updates rather than typing all the 1000 updates manually?

Any leads on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which body you would like to build
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def data = new ArrayList()

   1.upto(1000, {
       def entry = new groovy.json.internal.LazyMap()
       entry.put('timestamp', new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:S ZZZZ') as String)
       entry.put('value1', it)
       data.add(entry)

   })

   def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

   builder(
           api_key: "xxxxxx",

           updates: data.collect {
               [
                       timestamp: it.get('timestamp'),
                       value1   : it.get('value1')
               ]
           }
   )
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
   ```
3. That's it, your request body will be built from Groovy code (amend it if required according to your needs)

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I have a csv file with timestamp,value1. I have another csv with id, api_key. I tried to use the above code in the JSR223 PreProcessor. How do i use the data from the csv files in the code. I didn't quite understand that part. Thanks for helping out. @Dmitri